# Get array of directories in documents directory

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I am trying to return the list of directories present in an app's Documents directory. I am able to get an array containing all files of a given extension (eg .txt files or .png files) and am able to return all contents (including directories). The problem arises when I want to return only the directories. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Here is my code for returning all .txt files:

```
- (ViewController *) init {
    if (self = [super init]) self.title = @"Text Files";

    // get the list of .txt files
    directoryList = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] 
                      pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@".txt", nil]] retain];
    NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);

    return self;
}
```

and for all of the files

```
- (ViewController *) init {
    if (self = [super init]) self.title = @"Text Files";

    // get the list of all files and directories
    directoryList = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] retain];

    NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (ViewController *) init {
    if (self = [super init]) self.title = @"Text Files";

    // get the list of all files and directories
    NSFileManager *fM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileList = [[fM directoryContentsAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] retain];
    NSMutableArray *directoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *file in fileList) {
        NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        [fM fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:(&isDir)];
        if(isDir) {
            [directoryList addObject:file];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer subw. Didn't know of the fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: instance method; I'll have a read up of the NSFileManager documentation.

Comment: directoryContentsOfPath: is deprecated. Must be subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath: instead

Comment: @DerWOK Those two methods do very different things. `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` lists subpaths **recursively**. The correct replacement for `directoryContentsAtPath:` is  `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`

Answer (score 2):

Mrueg wrote it all but one thing that

```
fileList = [[fM directoryContentsAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
```

Replace by

```
fileList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Comment: Correct. "directoryContentsAtPath" is deprecated.