# Issue in showing already created folder

Tags: iphone, xcode, directory, nsfilemanager

I have been successful in creating folder in "Documents" folder in iPhone simulator.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
NSLog(@"path is:%@",dataPath);

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

I can see folder is created in simulator...
Now I require to show that folder in my app screen. **Means user can see( by clicking on '+' or anything else) that folder is created.**

I have also referred [iPhone/iPad: Unable to copy folder from NSBundle to NSDocumentDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059737/iphone-ipad-unable-to-copy-folder-from-nsbundle-to-nsdocumentdirectory) but not as I require.....

Is is possible to show folder, created?? If yes, then how?? 
Any help would be appreciated....

Thanx in advance :) :)

Comment: You have to program the user interface to access directories yourself, e.g. with table view(s). Is this what you mean?

Comment: I want to show that folder on my .xib file that's what I mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show the folder in the nib. A folder is not an object you can pull out from the object library. If you want an actual folder, you could use a UIImageView with an image of a folder. Also, if you are creating directories inside of the Documents folder, I would suggest using NSFileManager's methods for creating directories:

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

or

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtURL:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that either current item is folder or not by....

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtURL:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, that's how you read in all existing directories:

[Get array of directories in documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172245/get-array-of-directories-in-documents-directory)

You can then easily show them in a table in your view.